# how to destroy a cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am creating a cookie, reading it and then I want to destroy it.
How do I do that?

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) { //create a cookie to store authorisation details on the clients machine
if (days) {
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();

}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
 }


 function readCookie(name) { //read the cookie on the clients machine
 var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
 var c = ca[i];
 while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
  }
 return null;
 }
```

I want to expire this cookie when the user presses the logout button

Answer (score 0):

You can set expire date in past.

```
function deleteCookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;';
}
```

or something simillar

Comment: and as far as I know it's the only way. You just have to set expire date before now.

Comment: Yes but that will expire it,, I want it to be delete when the user presses logout button, on refresh it delete it But I havent written anycode for that, is there any way, where I can refresh the page whne logout is pressed

Comment: @user3051827 You cannot force client browser to physically delete cookie. You can only set it as expired and store rubbish into its value.